# How to Dynamically generate LUIS intents, Entities, patterns, utterances based on FAQ Knowledgebase

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have close to 50 unique set of FAQs in 50 different excel files with 100 s of Questions and Answers in each excel file.Is there a way I can dynamically generate all my LUIS intents, Entities, patterns, utterances etc and generate LUIS Apps.

I tried google, but could not find any relevant documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an application JSON file which can be imported into LUIS with this [API call](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c31). Just parse your excel files and create the JSON file.

You can also use a tool specialised just for that, like [QnA Maker](https://www.qnamaker.ai/).